# SoapUI/Groovy dynamically compare JSON response against array

Tags: arrays, json, groovy, soapui

I am trying to compare node values from a JSON response to values gathered from an excel spreadsheet which I have built an array for. The array contains values from multiple columns but I want to see if a JSON node value is in the array. Eventually I need to compare multiple node values to the array. I can't seem to get this to work for just one at the moment. What am I doing wrong??

```
import com.eviware.soapui.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import groovy.lang.*;
import groovy.util.*;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

//Create an array to hold the cell values
def cellValues = [];
//Get the JSON in a format to easily access
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context);
def ResponseMessage = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["ProductSkuLookupService"].getPropertyValue("response");
def jsonResult = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage);


//Get the number of recommended expressions nodes
def rspnsNumRcmndExprsns = jsonResult.product.recommendedExpressions.size();
//Get the file from the location specified in the test case custom properties
def String dataFilename = context.expand( '${#TestCase#dataFilename}' );

if(dataFilename != null && !dataFilename.equals(""))
{
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(dataFilename);
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("exprsnList");
    XSSFRow row; 
    XSSFCell cell;

    def totalNumRows;
    def numRows;
    //Get the total number of rows with data on the sheet
    totalNumRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    //log.info " The total number of rows are " + totalNumRows;
    //Get the number of rows without the header row
    numRows = totalNumRows - 1;
    //log.info " The number of rows to use are " + rows;

    def cols = 0;

    cols = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
    //log.info " The total number of columns are " + cols;

    if(numRows == rspnsNumRcmndExprsns)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < totalNumRows; i++)
        {
            row = sheet.getRow(i);
            //log.info " Row # " + i;

            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                //log.info "  Cell # " + j;
                cell = row.getCell(j);
                //log.info "  The value in the cell is " + cell;

                cellValues.push(cell);
            }

        }

        log.info jsonResult.product["recommendedExpressions"]["imageUrl"].every{it in [cellValues]}

    }

    else
    {
        assert false, "The number of nodes does not match the number of rows.";
    }
}
else
{
    assert false, "The file name is missing.";
}

return;
```

Here's a piece of the JSON (there are multiple sub-arrays in the JSON):

```
{
   "responseHeader":    {
      "status": "SUCCESS",
      "messages": []
   },
   "product":    {
      "recommendedExpressions":       [
                  {
            "imageUrl": "/images/products/expressions/ex015.jpg",
            "id": "sku83283exp",
            "description": " ",
            "code": "EX015"
         },
                  {
            "imageUrl": "/images/products/expressions/ex100.jpg",
            "id": "sku81486exp",
            "description": " ",
            "code": "EX100"
         },
                  {
            "imageUrl": "/images/products/expressions/ex036.jpg",
            "id": "sku82518exp",
            "description": " ",
            "code": "EX036"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Storing responses in Excel seems a little crazy?

Comment: Not actually storing the response in Excel ... my test data (validation data) is given to me in excel. I am putting that into an array. From there I want to compare the response to the array.

Comment: What does the array look like?

Comment: The code for the array is provided above.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing Cell to the array. I think your requirement is push cell contents to the array.

In place of this :

```
for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                //log.info "  Cell # " + j;
                cell = row.getCell(j);
                //log.info "  The value in the cell is " + cell;

                cellValues.push(cell);
            }
```

Use below code

```
for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                //log.info "  Cell # " + j;
                cell = row.getCell(j);
                //log.info "  The value in the cell is " + cell;

                cellValues.push(cell.getStringCellValue());
            }
```